# GTK3 : gtk_widget_destroy versus gtk_widget_hide

Tags: c, gtk3

Here a short MCV to illustrate the problem I meet :

I call a dialog box from my main window.
I click on one of the buttons from the dialog (usual way I think)
If I click again on one button, dialog will not display again (I got a bunch of   errors instead).
This doesn't happen of I use gtk_widget_hide instead.
(interfaces are designed with Glade3)

```
typedef struct {
    GtkBuilder *builder;
    gchar *stuff;
} Context;

void conDisplay(GtkWidget *g, gpointer userdata) {
    GtkWidget *dlg, *parent;
    Context *ctx=(Context *)userdata;
    int ret=0;

    g_printerr("clicked\n");

    parent=GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(ctx->builder,(gchar *)"MCV"));
    if (ctx->stuff) {
        g_printerr("Already connected\n");
        dlg=GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(ctx->builder,(gchar *)"question"));
        gtk_window_set_transient_for(GTK_WINDOW(dlg),GTK_WINDOW(parent));
        ret=gtk_dialog_run(dlg);
        if (ret==-3) { // OK clicked
            g_printerr("OK from Already connected\n");
        }
        else { g_printerr("Unknown\n"); }
        gtk_window_set_transient_for(GTK_WINDOW(dlg),NULL);
        gtk_widget_destroy(GTK_WIDGET(dlg));
    } else {
        dlg=GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(ctx->builder,(gchar *)"connect"));
        gtk_window_set_transient_for(GTK_WINDOW(dlg),GTK_WINDOW(parent));
        ret=gtk_dialog_run(dlg);
        if (ret==-1) { // GO clicked
            g_printerr("GO\n");
            ctx->stuff="Hello";
        }
        else { g_printerr("Cancel\n"); }
        gtk_window_set_transient_for(GTK_WINDOW(dlg),NULL);
        gtk_widget_destroy(GTK_WIDGET(dlg));
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    Context ctx;
    GtkWidget *mainwin;
    GtkWidget *btnCon;
    GError *error=NULL;

    /* Init GTK+ */
    gtk_init(&argc,&argv);
    ctx.builder=gtk_builder_new();
    ctx.stuff=NULL;
    // Load UI from file.
    gtk_builder_add_from_file(ctx.builder,"mcv.glade",&error);

    mainwin=GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(ctx.builder,(gchar *)"MCV"));
    btnCon=GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(ctx.builder,(gchar *)"con"));
    g_signal_connect(btnCon, "clicked", (GCallback)conDisplay, &ctx);

    gtk_widget_show_all(mainwin);

    gtk_main();
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks for your help !

Best regards.

V.

Comment: If you destroy your widget, how should it be possible to use it again without creating it first? Hiding does not destroy and it can be reused agein.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's clear and obvious (when read) but with widget_hide, I will not release memory and it can be a problem !

Answer (score 0):

From [GtkBuilder](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.22/GtkBuilder.html#GtkBuilder.description):

> A GtkBuilder holds a reference to all objects that it has constructed and drops these references when it is finalized. This finalization can cause the destruction of non-widget objects or widgets which are not contained in a toplevel window. For toplevel windows constructed by a builder, it is the responsibility of the user to call gtk_widget_destroy() to get rid of them and all the widgets they contain.

Since [GtkDialog inherits from `GtkWindow`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.22/GtkDialog.html#GtkDialog.object-hierarchy)  I would suggest separating `mainwin` and `dlg` GtkBuilders and gladefiles and use temporary `GtkBuilder` in `conDisplay`:

```
void conDisplay(GtkWidget *g, gpointer userdata) {
    GtkWidget *dlg, *parent;
    Context *ctx=(Context *)userdata;
    GtkBuilder *builder = gtk_builder_new_from_file("dlg.glade"); //or even pass glade filename in Context
    /* rest of the code */
    gtk_widget_destroy(GTK_WIDGET(dlg));
    g_object_unref(G_OBJECT(builder));
}
```